# Using global.asa on Windows 2008

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2008, global.asa

We have an old asp solution with VB6 components, which we are trying to install on Windows 2008.

There is a connection string that is assigned to a varibale in the global.asa.

When we try to use this the variable is not set. It appears that the global.asa is not run.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I would modify that slightly to the root of your "Web Application" *(this can be the root of your website or a Sub Web Application at another level in the hierarchy)*.

Comment: Make sure the global.asa is in the root of your web application.

Comment: @Lankymart thanks, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global.asa should work in the same way as before. Can you try a simple .asp page, that doesn't use VB6 components, but just displays the variable you set in the global.asa?
My guess is that classic ASP might not be enabled at all on your 2008 server.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the directory that contains the global.asa is set as an application. To do this  right click on the right virtual directory and choose 'Convert To Application'.